# Node Synchronous functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi there i am having awful trouble with a function I am trying to execute. 
I am trying to concat, compile and minify some `js` and `coffeescript` which i had working fine when i had it hard coded. My issue is i now created a function that search for the files and returns an array with the file paths. But i cant get the the function to in a synchronous fashion. I have tried so many thing just cant figure it out.

At this stage this is what i have,

This function is used to compile the coffee script this is also called by a async.series which works fine. You can see it calls getFiles which should return the array. But the callback seem to fire before the data s retured

```
function compileCoffee() {

    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            data = getFiles("coffee");
            callback(null, data)
        },
        function(data, callback) {
            console.log(data)
            shell.echo(grey("Compiling CoffeeScript files .... "));
            if (shell.cat(data).exec('coffee -sc').exec('uglifyjs --compress', {
                    silent: true
                }).to('./public/assets/js/app.min.js').code !== 0) {
                shell.echo(red('Coffee script compile error'));
                shell.exit(1);
            }
            shell.echo(green("CoffeeScript files compiled succesfully"));
        },
    ], () => {});
}
```

Then this is the get files function. I am probly going abut this all wrong, if i am please let me know a better way. If not and you know how to get it working would be amazing.

```
function getFiles(filetype, callback) {

    var files = [];

    // Walker options
    var walker = walk.walkSync('./frontend/js', {
        followLinks: false
    });

    walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
            // Add this file to the list of files
        var ext = stat.name.substr(stat.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        if (ext == filetype) {
            files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
        }
        next();
    });

    walker.on('end', function() {
        console.lof(files)
        return files
    })

}
```

Please some one help :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getFiles` doesn't actually return anything, but it does take a callback that should be called when `getFiles` completes. Pass the `async` callback to `getFiles` (or create another function that calls the callback):

```
function(callback) {
  data = getFiles("coffee", callback);
},
```

You need to actually call this callback in your `getFiles` function:

```
walker.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error)
    callback(error);
});
walker.on('end', function() {
    console.log(files)
    callback(null, files);
});
```

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you ,  but when i do this it returns a function when i log data in the following of the series it shows as [function]

Comment: @AlexKirwan which `console.log`? Maybe you can create another question that has the details of this